# Restful GET endpoint - huge response data causing poor performance

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, rest

I have a restful GET method implementation using spring-boot and postgresql as database, and it fetches huge amount of data for a single call(almost 7 mb). During load testing I found it is causing very poor throughput.

Pagination is not an option here as application is not UI based, and client service needs entire data in a single call.

What possible approaches I can have to improve the performance?

Comment: Gzip the response body.

Comment: You can try filtering out the parts that aren't important, and compressing the parts that are.

Comment: for such a large data you might have to use pagination between server to server with offset and limit. Pagination is not only for UI. If your client service needs all the data in single response then other option is to use a good compression mechanism. Other options is transferring data using queue mechanism.

Comment: How poor is "very poor"?  For all we know, you are already at the limit of your network speed.

Comment: I get throughput of around 5/sec in jmeter test.